# Found multiple catalog/schemas matching null.PUBLIC - Hsqldb / Liquibase

Tags: java, maven, jira, hsqldb, liquibase

I am using Atlassian Jira SDK with liquibase and hsqldb 1.8.

When I run the liquibase maven plugin to install the database schema, the follow error is printed:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.2.2:update (default-cli) on project portal-db: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.snapshot.InvalidExampleException: Found multiple catalog/schemas matching null.PUBLIC -> [Help 1]

- Java Version: 1.6
- Jira SDK: 5.0.4
- Hsqldb: 1.8
- Liquibase: 3.2.2

How it is possible to fix this? thanks for reading.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do with Liquibase and HSQLDB, and how does that relate to your use of JIRA?

Comment: Hi. I am using sdk to develop some jira plugins. 

In the jira local database (HSQLDB), I need to create some custom tables as part of my plugins.

Comment: I would like to run liquibase and apply de custom sql objects in this HSQLDB.

Comment: It sounds like your HSQL may be trying to use the same data files as JIRA's own HSQL. Storing data inside the JIRA database directly is discouraged for various reasons; I suspect you need to try to configure your copy of HSQL to instantiate a new database somewhere other than the default location. I am not an HSQL expert, but you might also need to explicitly bundle HSQL with scope=compile, in addition to whatever configuration is needed of the data store location.

Comment: Thks, I will try to create another database instance for my custom database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write a JIRA add-on that has its own tables in the same database as JIRA I'd recommend [Active Objects](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Active+Objects).

From the Atlassian documentation:

> Active Objects is a new ORM (object relational mapping) layer into Atlassian products. Active Objects is implemented as a plugin into Atlassian applications. It enables easier, faster, and more scalable data access and storage than the existing Bandana and PluginSettings APIs.
>
> The goal of the Active Objects plugin is to provide a plugin data storage component that plugins can and should use to persist their private data. ...